# Defining and comparing TIMESTAMP variable with jQuery/Javascript ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, css

I have a table with a column using the timestamp variable from a oracle DB. Im uncertain of how to use JQuery to define my var "schedule Time" from the SQL Query and run the condition. Im basically comparing column timestamp to system time and returning a row background color.

ps. my table is within aspx page

```
// declaring the time

var currentTime = new Date();
var scheduledTime = "not sure how to declare the variable from my dynamic table"

// variables for the table
var rows = document.getElementById('ewGrid').getElementbyTagName('tr');

 // style class
.rowRed {background-color:red; color:white;}
.rowYellow {background-color:red; color white} 


$('tr').each(function() {
// if value is a number and less then zero
if (currentTime - scheduledTime) >15mins<=30mins ) {
    tr = $(this).parent();
    tr.addClass("rowRed");
 }

 });
```

Thank for any help

Answer (score 0):

unix timestamp has an accuration of second, so convert to milisecond and pass to Date constructor:

```
var scheduledTime = new Date(unixtimestamp*1000)
// where unixtimestamp is the timestamp you get from the database
```